# Why Berliner Sparkasse?

Tags: noun

Hmm.. this is something I do not understand so far hmm. when I say I am from Berlin I could say (Ich bin ein Berliner) here I though Berlin became like an adjectival noun. But one thing I found a bit strange was Berliner Sparkasse. Kasse is feminine so I thought it should be Berline Sparkasse. What is going on here?

Comment: Look at "Adjective endings". Feminine without an article in Genitiv gets -er ending.

Comment: @vahancho.. this is not helping/misleading. It's called "die Berliner Sparkasse"

Comment: @vahancho: Neither is this true (the adjective ending in the case you describe is -e, not -er), nor is it related in any way to the question, as "Berlin" as such is not an adjective whose ending gets changed here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Berliner" is a standard adjectival derivative of a proper geografical noun which carries the ending -er regardless of the gender of the noun:

> Der Berliner Raum
>
> Die Berliner Sparkasse
>
> Das Berliner Straßennetz

What is more, "Berliner" is never inflected:

```
Der Berliner Raum
Des Berliner Raums
Dem Berliner Raum
Den Berliner Raum
```

Same with "Wiener", "Stuttgarter", "Hamburger", etc.

It is another question if you add the syllable "isch":

> Die berlinerische Lebensart

which carries flections but also implies a different meaning, as "die berlinerische Lebensart" might also be found elsewhere, but "das Berliner Straßennetz" only in Berlin.

The capitalization of "Berliner" is due to §61 of the [orthographical rules](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) of the Council for German Orthography (Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung), whereas §62 commands to lowercase "berlinerisch".

Comment: Also, it is capitalised. Not so sure about “berlin(er)such", though.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Thank you for the correction. Rechtschreibregeln §62: Kleingeschrieben werden adjektivische Ableitungen von Eigennamen auf -(i)sch, außer wenn die Grundform eines Personennamens durch einen Apostroph verdeutlicht wird, ferner alle adjektivischen 
Ableitungen mit anderen Suffixen.

Comment: Argh, autocorrect got me.

Comment: I will take this answer as many people here opt for this answer. Hmm.. quite interesting to see some rather conflicting answers here.

Answer (score 7):

Another examples of this kind:

> Schweizer Käse, Kölner Dom, Frankfurter Würstchen

and:

> des Schweizer Käses, vom Kölner Dom, satt von Frankfurter Würstchen

This is somewhat special. Adjectives derived from city names end always with "-er" and are not declinated whatsoever.

Comment: It is not only city names, "Badener", "Thüringer", etc. are valid, as well.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is feminine: "*die* Sparkasse".

But, in this case "Berliner" is related to its home city Berlin and therefore is another form of "Sparkasse of Berlin" or "Sparkasse von Berlin".

Answer (score 0):

In my view  in such forms as  Münchner Bier, Thüringer Bratwürste etc "Berliner" and "Münchner" are no adjectives as they are invariable but genitive plural forms derived from "Bier der Münchner" and "Bratwürste der Thüringer" with the genitive placed before the noun as in Latin Romanorum lingua ( literal: of the Romans + language) or as in literary formulas as "der Menschen Schicksal".

Answer (score 0):

Berliner (and the like) is usually called an indeclinable adjective, but, at least historically, it is a noun meaning “inhabitant of Berlin”, and, being a noun, it is written with an upper-case B, Hence:

der Berliner

des Berliners

dem Berliner

den Berliner

die Berliner

der Berliner

den Berlinern

die Berliner

In “Berliner Wurst” (etc.) Berliner is (again, at least historically) the genitive plural of the word for “inhabitant of Berlin”, “the Berliners’ sausage”, as Roger has explained.

Comment: What is wrong with this?