# Genitiv bei geografischen Namen

Tags: grammaticality, genitive, inflection

Ein Ausdruck fällt mir auf während meines Übens:

> der **Dresdener** Striezelmarkt

Kann ich stattdessen **der Dresdens Striezelmarkt** schreiben?

Im Grammatikbuch wird es so erklärt:

> *Einige* geografische Bezeichnungen werden als substantiviertes Adjektiv im Genitiv vor ein Nomen gesetzt: Berliner Luft, Kölner Dom.

Aber in welchen Fällen soll ich so benutzen?

Comment: Der Artikel muss dann weggelassen werden: "Ich besuche Dresdens Striezelmarkt" (ohne "der").

Comment: Warum? Draf ich nicht "den Dresdens Striezelmarkt besuchen" sagen?

Comment: Nein, das ist falsch. Ich kann aber nicht erklaeren warum das so ist. Genauso kann ich nicht sagen "Ich atme die Berlins Luft", aber "Ich atme Berlins Luft". Der Artikel ist noetig bei "Ich atme die Berliner Luft" und "Ich atme die Luft Berlins".

Comment: Übrigens ist die Grammatikbuch-Erklärung Unsinn. "Berliner Luft" ist absolut kein *substantiviertes Adjektiv*, sondern ein als Adjektiv benutzter Eigenname.

Comment: Siehe auch:  https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/why-berliner-sparkasse

Answer (score 3):

In this context "Dresdener" (or "Dresdner") is an adjective associated to the city of Dresden. It means *belonging to Dresden*. See [here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/K%C3%B6lner). This very special type of adjective is not in genitive - it is **indeclinable**. In contrast to other adjectives it is spelled with a capital letter at the beginning. Also there are no comparative and superlative forms.

Answer (score 2):

Die Antwort hast du dir eigentlich schon selbst gegeben: Wenn du es als Adjektiv nutzen möchtest.

Oft lassen sich damit Eigennamen formulieren oder der Ort besonders hervorheben (Berliner Luft  ist der Name eines Schnaps, Lübecker Marzipan ist das besondere, bekannte Marzipan aus Lübeck).

Der Dresdener Striezelmarkt ist eben der Markt in *Dresden*, während der Striezelmarkt Dresdens eher Betonung auf den *Markt* setzt und dass er in Dresden ist wird zur weniger wichtigen Nebeninformation.

Comment: As a side note, for me at least "Dresdens Striezelmarkt" implies that there is only one Striezelmarkt in Dresden, while "der Dresdener Striezelmarkt" just says that there is a Striezelmarkt known by this specific name, but there could be other Striezelmärkte too.